# MEF: Could not load file or assembly 'Facebook'

Tags: c#, mef

Doing this:

```
   var _partsCatalog = new DirectoryCatalog(directoryName);//Fully qualified path to our bin folder
   var partInfos = partsCatalog 
                .Parts
                .Select(pd => new PartDefinitionInfo(pd))
                .ToArray(); <<-- this throws
```

Throws an exception : "Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information." with the LoaderExceptions set to :

> {"Could not load file or assembly 'Facebook, Version=5.4.1.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=58cb4f2111d1e6de'  or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.": "Facebook,
>   Version=5.4.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=58cb4f2111d1e6de"}

Granted, one of my assemblies is referencing the Facebook.Web.dll , which causes it to be copied into the bin folder, which causes it to be part of the directory catalogue, kinda unintentionally, but stil...

But why would it throw this error?

Comment: I'm not really familiar with the facebook api, but...  Is Facebook.dll in your bin folder as well?  Facebook.Web.dll may have a dependency on Facebook.dll. Also, one way to get more details about it is to use Fusion log viewer. Here is a good post on how to use it. http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsUsingFusionLogViewerToDebugObscureLoaderErrors.aspx

Comment: there is a reference missing. you should first find the one who cause that problem. i use a directorycatalog in my project and filter some dll's out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Granted, one of my assemblies is referencing the Facebook.Web.dll

From the [Getting Started](http://facebook.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20Started) guide: "Add references to Facebook.dll and Facebook.Web.dll". You need to reference both.

> But why would it throw this error?

The error message says it all: something has a dependency on Facebook.dll, but the .NET runtime was unable to load that dll, because it cannot find it in the bin folder: "*The system cannot find the file specified*".